# Counting value from various columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table

```
school code   school_name subcode1 subcode2 subcode3 
001               xyz      56        55     54
002               abc      55        56     54
003               xyz      54        55     56
```

Suppose 56=english or 55=hindi and I want to check that school xyz is have how many English subject or how many Hindi subject etc.

I have used `count(*)` function on where condition like:

```
select count(*) 
from schooltable 
where (subcode1 = '55' or subcode2 = '55' or subcode3 = 55) 
  and school_name='abc'
```

But it give only the one result I want get all records about all schools and want to insert it like this

```
scode schoolname sub   sub    sub
                 eng  hindi  history
001     abc      3      2      3
```

Help required.

Comment: Is 'school code' a primary key, and do you want the grouping on 'school_name'?

Answer (score 0):

you could do a conditional sum, something like this

```
select sum(case when subcode1='55' or subcode2='55' or subcode3=55 then 1 else 0 end) as hindi,
       sum(case when subcode1='56' or subcode2='56' or subcode3=56 then 1 else 0 end) as english
from schooltable 
--where school_name='abc'    (not sure if you really require this constraint, although you have it in your question)
```

you could add a GROUP BY clause if required, but this would depend on your exact requirements, database structure, primary keys, etc. But the above should at least get you started.

Comment: Instead of the 'where' i think OP wants a GROUP BY school name.

Comment: OP also has that WHERE clause. No WHERE clause or GROUP BY would seem to make more sense, but it is what the OP had in his question. I believe he is mainly interested in the conditional sum part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select school_name,count(*) as TotalSub from schooltable
  group by school_name, subcode1,subcode2,subcode3
  having school_name = 'abc'
```